# Grails : Error initializing spring security on server restart

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have a very strange behaviour on a production server.

When I start for the first time my server, there is no problem, but when I want to stop and restart it, I get the following error :

```
Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core

2013-10-31 12:03:08,156 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.aftmevent.security.UserRole.create(UserRole.groovy:32)
        at BootStrap$_closure1.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:16)
        at grails.util.Environment.evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock(Environment.java:308)
        at grails.util.Environment.executeForEnvironment(Environment.java:301)
        at grails.util.Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment(Environment.java:277)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
2013-10-31 12:03:08,156 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing Grails: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.aftmevent.security.UserRole.create(UserRole.groovy:32)
        at BootStrap$_closure1.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:16)
        at grails.util.Environment.evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock(Environment.java:308)
        at grails.util.Environment.executeForEnvironment(Environment.java:301)
        at grails.util.Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment(Environment.java:277)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
oct. 31, 2013 12:03:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
```

Here is my BootStrap.groovy :

```
class BootStrap {

    def springSecurityService
    def init = { servletContext ->
        def existingAdminRole = Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')
        def existingUserRole = null
        def existingAdminUser = null
        if (existingAdminRole) {
            existingUserRole = UserRole.findByRole(existingAdminRole)
        }
        if (existingUserRole) {
            existingAdminUser = existingUserRole.user
        }
        if (!existingAdminUser) {
            def adminRole = new Role(authority: 'ROLE_ADMIN')
            def adminUser = new User(username: 'admin', password: 'admin', enabled: true)
            if (adminRole.validate()) {
                adminRole.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
            }
            if (adminUser.validate()) {
                adminUser.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
            }
            UserRole userRole = UserRole.create(adminUser, adminRole, true)
            if (userRole.validate()) {
                userRole.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
            }
        }
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

Here is my User.groovy (adding the nullable constraint did not solve the problem) :

User.groovy :

```
class User {

    transient springSecurityService

    String username
    String password
    boolean enabled
    boolean accountExpired
    boolean accountLocked
    boolean passwordExpired

    static constraints = {
        username nullable: true, blank: false, unique: true
        password nullable: true, blank: false
    }

    static mapping = {
        password column: '`password`'
    }

    Set<Role> getAuthorities() {
        UserRole.findAllByUser(this).collect { it.role } as Set
    }

    def beforeInsert() {
        encodePassword()
    }

    def beforeUpdate() {
        if (isDirty('password')) {
            encodePassword()
        }
    }

    protected void encodePassword() {
        password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password)
    }
}
```

Here are my classe Role.groovy and UserRole.groovy :

Role.groovy :

```
class Role {

    String authority

    static mapping = {
        cache true
    }

    static constraints = {
        authority nullable: true, blank: false, unique: true
    }
}
```

UserRole.groovy :

```
class UserRole implements Serializable {

    User user
    Role role

    boolean equals(other) {
        if (!(other instanceof UserRole)) {
            return false
        }

        other.user?.id == user?.id &&
            other.role?.id == role?.id
    }

    int hashCode() {
        def builder = new HashCodeBuilder()
        if (user) builder.append(user.id)
        if (role) builder.append(role.id)
        builder.toHashCode()
    }

    static UserRole get(long userId, long roleId) {
        find 'from UserRole where user.id=:userId and role.id=:roleId',
            [userId: userId, roleId: roleId]
    }

    static UserRole create(User user, Role role, boolean flush = false) {
        new UserRole(user: user, role: role).save(flush: flush, insert: true)
    }

    static boolean remove(User user, Role role, boolean flush = false) {
        UserRole instance = UserRole.findByUserAndRole(user, role)
        if (!instance) {
            return false
        }

        instance.delete(flush: flush)
        true
    }

    static void removeAll(User user) {
        executeUpdate 'DELETE FROM UserRole WHERE user=:user', [user: user]
    }

    static void removeAll(Role role) {
        executeUpdate 'DELETE FROM UserRole WHERE role=:role', [role: role]
    }

    static mapping = {
        id composite: ['role', 'user']
        version false
    }
}
```

Here is my DataSource.groovy file with the database settings :

```
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            driverClassName = 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
            username = 'root'
            password = 'root'
            url = 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database?autoreconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8'
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = 'create-drop'
            driverClassName = 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'
            username = 'root'
            password = 'root'
            url = 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database?autoreconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8'
        }
    }
}
```

I really don't have any idea about what occured.
I have added the nullable constrainst, trying to put the databe into 'create-drop' / 'update'.

Funny thing : When I drop the databse then create it again, the first server start is good, but crash after a restart.

I try to put println logs into my BootStrap.groovy, I can see them into development environment, but not into production server.

So I'm not sure if my BootStrap is updated creating war.

I create the war using :

```
grails prod war target/my-new-war-0.0.x.war
```

Thanks for reading,

Snite

Comment: My guess is missing imports, that's what seems to be the most common issue for me when creating things from the BootStrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all of your answer which help me to solve my issue.

It was stupid but in my rundeck script to deploy the war on the production server, it was an out of date version of the war which was used -*_*-

So doint it manually with the correct war version solve my problem.

Thanks because your advices help me to read adequat documentation on grails's framework and help me thinking looking here.

Cheers,

Snite

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what's wrong with your code, however your giant block of code was making my head hurt so I had to post this.

```
Role role = Role.findByAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN") ?: new Role(authority: "ROLE_ADMIN").save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

if (UserRole.countByRole(role) == 0) {
    User user = new User(username: 'admin', password: 'admin', enabled: true).save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
    UserRole.create(user, role, true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hmmm well its a null point exception:

ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
        **at com.aftmevent.security.UserRole.create(UserRole.groovy:32)
        at BootStrap$_closure1.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:16)**

Unsure if the pasted content matches up exactly to your own line numbers, something you could try for now is by going around and adding the question mark :

```
def existingAdminRole = Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')
        def existingUserRole = null
        def existingAdminUser = null
        if (existingAdminRole) {
            existingUserRole = UserRole.findByRole(existingAdminRole)
        }
        if (existingUserRole) {
            existingAdminUser = existingUserRole.user
        }
```

change to:

```
def existingAdminRole = Role?.findByAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN')
        def existingUserRole = null
        def existingAdminUser = null
        if (existingAdminRole) {
            existingUserRole = UserRole?.findByRole(existingAdminRole)
        }
        if (existingUserRole) {
            existingAdminUser = existingUserRole?.user
        }
```

Also you could try findorsavewhere rather than an attempt to generate a new record:
https://github.com/vahidhedayati/ajaxdependancyselectexample/blob/master/grails-app/conf/BootStrap.groovy

```
 def n1=MyContinent.findOrSaveWhere(continentName: 'Asia')
                def n2=MyContinent.findOrSaveWhere(continentName: 'Europe')

                // Create countries and provde continent map value as above defs
                def c1 = MyCountry.findOrSaveWhere(mycontinent: n2, countryName:'United Kingdom',ccode:'GB',language:'')
                def c2 = MyCountry.findOrSaveWhere(mycontinent: n2, countryName:'France',ccode:'FR',language:'')
                def c3 = MyCountry.findOrSaveWhere(mycontinent: n1, countryName:'China',ccode:'CN',language:'')
                def c4 = MyCountry.findOrSaveWhere(mycontinent: n1, countryName:'India',ccode:'IN',language:'')
```

you will need to figure out what is going on in line 32 of UserRole which will be the start of your issue followed by BootStrap on line 16..